# IntelliJ How can I get Build | Rebuild to generate POJO from XSD files and compile them

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, xsd

This question is specific to **IntelliJ**.  I'll also post this to the IntelliJ Support Community site at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics.
I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ which is 2023.3.4 (Build #IU-233.14475.28, built on February 13, 2024).

I'm currently using the maven plugin **com.evolvedbinary.maven.jvnet:jaxb30-maven-plugin:0.15.0** 
to take *.XSD files and generate POJOs from the XSDs and compile the POJOs into classes for use in my application.

A snippet of my directory structure (for the purposes of this question is):

```
maven-module1/ 
    src/main/java/org/acme/myapp/Main.java
    src/main/resources/xsd/myData.xsd
```

After running `mvn clean install`, the XJB plugin generates sources and maven compiles them and places them into the target/classes directory along with other compiled Java files.   Below shows the resultant `target/classes` and `target/generated-sources` directories.

```
maven-module1/ 
    target/generated-sources/xjc/org/acme/myapp/myData.java 
    target/classes/org/acme/myapp/Main.class
    target/classes/org/acme/myapp/myData.class
```

So my generated sources are not put into a normal `src/main/java` sub-directory but instead put into a sub-directory inside of the target directory.

```
    <properties> 
          <maven-jaxb30-plugin-version>0.15.0</maven-jaxb30-plugin-version> 
    </properties> 
 
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId>com.evolvedbinary.maven.jvnet</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>jaxb30-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                    <version>${maven-jaxb30-plugin-version}</version> 
                    <executions> 
                        <execution> 
                            <goals> 
                                <goal>generate</goal> 
                            </goals> 
                        </execution> 
                    </executions> 
                    <configuration> 
                        <strict>false</strict> 
                        <schemaIncludes>**/xsd/*.xsd</schemaIncludes> 
                        <bindingIncludes>**/xjb/*.xjb</bindingIncludes> 
                        <useDependenciesAsEpisodes>false</useDependenciesAsEpisoes> 
                    </configuration> 
                </plugin>
```

**How can I get IntelliJ to use this maven plugin to generate the source code an compile the source code?**

### What I've tried

NOTE: I've already tried using the IntellIJ plugin described at
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-java-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-dialog.html

And found that it had limitations (it wouldn't allow me to enter the output directory of target/generated-sources)

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

1. When I switch to a new git branch and
2. Run Build | Rebuild module "my-module-with-xsds-in-it", that
3. IntelliJ generates the POJOs and compiles them.

Currently, my work around is to run maven clean install from the command line of that maven module directory  to have the XSD POJOs generated and compiled.

Comment: Did you try with original plugin (not the forked one) ? Documentation [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools). You can use latest version (`org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin:4.0.3`) for generating jakarta classes. All other parameters are the same

Comment: I haven't yet.  I'm using `com.evolvedbinary.maven.jvnet:jaxb30-maven-plugin:0.15.0`, are they compatible?  I don't know anything about either of these plugins.

Comment: The evolvedbinary plugin is a fork of the initial. Just do a dropin replacement of groupId/artifactId/version with those I send

Comment: i tried just changing the artifact information but got errors.  When looking at the `xjb/bindings.xjb` file I see that IntelliJ says this wasn't found `jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"`.

Comment: The `extensionBindingPrefixes` is a special attribute in jaxb:bindings which is not always recognized by IDE (eclipse or intellij)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following answer from IntelliJ/JetBrains tech support:

> It's not possible to set custom tool for file generation.

URL: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/17057858486418-IntelliJ-generating-Java-POJOs-from-XSD-and-compiling-the-generated-code

Answer (score 1):

You can go into Settings > Build > Build Tools > Maven > Runner and select **Delegate**.

The documentation for this feature is at: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#delegate_to_maven

That link says:

> By default, IntelliJ IDEA uses the native IntelliJ IDEA builder to build a Maven project. It might be helpful if you have a pure Java or a Kotlin project since IntelliJ IDEA supports the incremental build which significantly speeds up the building process. However, if you have a configuration that changes the compilation on the fly, or your build generates an artifact with a custom layout, then Maven is preferable for the building process.

Comment: This worked.  Can you provide a link to IntelliJ's documentation that explains it?  I'll look as well.

Comment: This did work to generate the Java POJOs from the XSD and compile them but it broke IntelliJ's ability to run tests.  The errors said that symbols are not found (I'm thinking because code was not compiled)

Comment: Here is the documentation for this feature. Not very helpful in this case: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#delegate_to_maven

Comment: I could fix the test run by using a "Modify option" on the run configuration of the test. I used "Add before launch task" to execute the maven goal "test-compile" before launching the test.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I updated your answer to include the link you provided, it's a best practice to a link supporting your answer and also including a key snippet of the information on that link (in case the link becomes broken).  I upvoted the answer but it's not quite the solution because it doesn't allow my unit tests to run after I've selected this.  If I can track this down, this might be the answer (with some additional information added)

Comment: Did you try my second comment?